# How use labels in transchoice()

Tags: symfony, machine-translation

I need to translate a french phrase depending of gender and quantity.
In message.fr.yml, I have :

```
key.toto: "male_singular: tu es venu 1 fois donc 1 vie|female_singular: tu es venue 1 fois donc 1 vie|male_plural: tu es venu %count% fois donc %count% vies|male_singular: tu es venue %count% fois donc %count% vies"
```

I see in doc of Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector used by transchoice()

> The indexed solution can also contain labels (e.g. one: There is one apple).
>
> This is purely for making the translations more clear - it does not affect the functionality.
>
> **The two methods can also be mixed:**
>
> **{0} There are no apples|one: There is one apple|more: There are %count% apples**

But when I call transchoice With a call like that

```
transchoice("key.toto", "female_singular", array(), "messages")
```

I have :

> "tu es venu 1 fois donc 1 vie"

instead of :

> "tu es venue 1 fois donc 1 vie"

I prefer use labels instead of {} because messages files are translated by another enterprise.

Any idea ?

Comment: I think you can mix labels and transchoice: `male_singular: tu es venu 1 fois donc 1 vie key.toto: "male_singular: %male_singular%|..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `Translation` component [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#pluralization):

> The tags are really only hints for translators and don't affect the
>   logic used to determine which plural form to use.

and

> As tags are optional, the translator doesn't use them (the translator
>   will only get a string based on its position in the string).

You can make sure if you open [the source code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php#L258) of `transChoice()` method:

```
public function transChoice($id, $number, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
{
    ...

    return strtr($this->selector->choose($catalogue->get($id, $domain), (int) $number, $locale), $parameters);
}
```

As you can see, `transChoice()` casts the `$number` parameter to int.

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) says that `PHP`converts `"female_singular"` to `0`:

```
<?php

echo (int) "female_singular"; //0
```

So when you do not specify the range in your transchoice string, `Translation` component make its choice based on the string position.

In your case(`number = 0`) it's the string: `"tu es venu 1 fois donc 1 vie"`.